# Navigation bar is not fully transparent in Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

As `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);` is not working in Android API 30. I tried another code from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
```

But the navigation bar is not fully transparent [(img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1L3l.png), like in Google apps.
How can I achieve a fully transparent navigation bar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it often comes you find a solution by yourself. 
I found the solution in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e). 
You just need to disable auto system content protection by this code `<item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>` in your theme.

Comment: This is the solution to my problem, thank you very much, here are my upvotes to both your question and answer.

Do accept this answer as the accepted one as it solves the problem

Comment: Instead of setting transparent navigation bar it changed a color of StatusBar.

Comment: @CoolMind, maybe you confusing something. Code above just disable system content protection on Android 10+ on NavigationBar by this code `<item name="android:enforceNavigationBarContrast">false</item>` and it has no effect on StatusBar. Though, there's code which do the same but with StatusBar `<item name="android:enforceStatusBarContrast">false</item>`

Comment: @CoolMind, read more about it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-going-edge-to-edge-812f62e4e83e#:~:text=Disabling%20system%20bar%20protection%20on%20Android%2010)